# jQuery draggable and droppable in Livewire component

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am working on a Laravel Livewire project.

On a page, there's a loop through workshops and within each loop, there's a loop through students who are attending the workshop.The admin should be able to drag students from one workshop to another. I am trying to achieve this using jQuery draggable droppable.

```
    <div wire:init"bindjquery">
                 @foreach($workshops as $workshop)
                   <div class="droppable" id="{{ $workshop->id }}">
                   @foreach($workshop->students as $student)
                    <div id="{{$student->id}}" data-event="{{$workshop->id}}" 
                    class="draggable">{{$student->name}}</div>
                   @endforeach
                  </div>
                @endforeach
    </div>
```

In the component:

```
public function bindjquery(){
        
        $this->emit('bindjquery');
    }
```

In the Blade template:

```
window.livewire.on('bindjquery', () => {
         
            $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
            });
   $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
   drop: handleDropEvent,
 });
 
 
              
              
         })

         function handleDropEvent(event,ui) {
  
    
     var dragId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
     var previousevent = ui.draggable.data("event");
     var dropId = $(this).attr("id");
     
     Livewire.emit('userdropped', dragId, dropId, previousevent);
    
 
   }
```

And then again in the Limewire component:

```
protected $listeners = ['userdropped' => 'userdropped'];

    public function userdropped($par1, $par2, $par3){
        $huidigevent = Event::find($par3);
        $huidigevent->gebruikers()->detach($par1);

        $nieuwevent = Event::find($par2);
        $nieuwevent->gebruikers()->attach($par1);

       
    }
```

This works ok. But only the first time after the page is loaded the drag movement is visible.

After that first movement the database gets updated en the component re-rendered. I still can grap a student, move to another workshop en drop him. All logic works, the actual dragging is not visualized.

What could be the problem?

Maybe relevant: I also use Alpine JS on that page..

Answer (score 0):

When livewire processes some data the response sent to the browser is the code required to re-render the view. In your case all the stuff in the foreach block is re-rendered. This is problematic for you because the javascript listeners **were bound to elements that in effect got deleted and new ones took their place**.

So how do we get around this? **Rebind the Javascript functions**

In your case I would add this to your userdropped function (last line)

```
$this->bindjquery();
```

That should retrigger the JS binding on the page.